# ValueError: supplied range of [-inf, -inf] is not finite

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When trying to plot these graphs, the line:

```
sub3.hist(x=np.log(df[i]), bins = 100, color="grey")
```

Gives the error:

ValueError: supplied range of [-inf, -inf] is not finite.

I don't understand this error and can't find any explanations online. Here is the full code. df and df_norm are pandas dataframes with identical data, save for df_norm being minmax normalised.

```
tb = widgets.TabBar([str(c) for c in range(16)])
k = 0
for c in range(len(df_norm.columns)):
  with tb.output_to(c, select=(c < 3)):
    colours = ["orange", "green"]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0., left = 0, top = 1., right = 1)
    p = 0
    g = 1   
    for i in df_norm.columns[k:k+2]:
      sub1 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,g)
      sub1.hist(x=df[i], bins = 100, alpha=0.3, color=colours[p])
      sub2 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,g+1)
      sub2.hist(x=df_norm[i], bins = 100, alpha=0.3, color=colours[p])
      sub3 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,g+2)
      sub3.hist(x=np.log(df[i]), bins = 100, color="grey")
      sub1.set_title(i)
      sub2.set_title('title ' + i)
      sub3.set_title('title ' + i)
      sub1.set_ylabel('label')
      p = p + 1
      k = k + 1
      g = g + 3
```

Edit, full stack trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-d6170fc0d99d> in <module>()
     20       sub2.hist(x=df_norm[i], bins = 100, alpha=0.3, color=colours[p])
     21       sub3 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,g+2) # two rows, two columns, second cell
---> 22       sub3.hist(x=np.log(df[i]), bins = 100, color="grey")
     23       sub1.set_title(i)
     24       sub2.set_title('title ' + i)

4 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in histogram(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py in _get_outer_edges(a, range)
    314         if not (np.isfinite(first_edge) and np.isfinite(last_edge)):
    315             raise ValueError(
--> 316                 "supplied range of [{}, {}] is not finite".format(first_edge, last_edge))
    317     elif a.size == 0:
    318         # handle empty arrays. Can't determine range, so use 0-1.

ValueError: supplied range of [-inf, -inf] is not finite
```

Comment: Can you share complete stack trace?

Comment: `-inf` is what you get from computing `np.log(0.)`. Don't do that. But a faster way to get there might be to not compute the log at all - instead configure the plot to have log scale. Either way, with all zeros in the data, the plot won't make much sense.

Comment: If you want to answer this I will accept it. I found an error adding a single 0 column to my very large dataset. Thanks a lot!